# Creating a table of the Erathosthenes sive

Tags: python

I am starting un python and In tried to solve this problem, but I cant print the table.
I tried to code this:
*Print a table of ones and zeros corresponding to the Eratosthenes sieve, where each line has 10 digits corresponding to the appropriate ten, separated by space. The first line continues the sieve from 0 to 9. The second line from 10 to 19, and so on. The 1 corresponds to not being a prime, and the 0 corresponds to being a prime.*
Can someone explain me how to print a table like this:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_prime(number): 
    if number in [0,1]: 
        return 1 # not prime
    i=2 
    while i<number: 
        if not number%i:     
            return 1 #not prime 
        i+=1  
    return 0 # If didn't fall, it's a prime number 


Erathostenes_table = np.array([is_prime(i) for i in np.arange(100)]).reshape(10,10)

for row in Erathostenes_table:
    print(' '.join([str(single_number) for single_number in row]))
```

Disclamer: 0 and 1 are not primer numbers.

Comment: This is not a Sieve of Eratosthenes. The whole point of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is to: 1. Not do any work for numbers already identified as prime, and 2. Do purely multiplication and (mostly) addition work, no division/remaindering. What you've written is wildly inefficient trial division, not a sieve at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I helped someone writing his exact problem description. However, it looks to me that now he can do multiplication and summation with that table and having o for prime (no work) and 1 for not prime (do work) will obtain what you refer as the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Anyway, you raised me the appetite to learn about it!